# Google Checkout: Offering Multiple Options when Adding to Cart

Tags: google-checkout

I'm using Google Checkout with a Merchant Account and I'm having difficulty with the Add to Cart code when I try to have multiple options for one product.

Specifically, I want to sell **Paint** and give customers two options: **Size** (5-gallon, gallon, quart) and **Color** (100s of colors) and only use one Add to Cart button:

**Paint**      **Size**    **Color**    **Add to Cart**

Is this possible? Or do I need to have three Add to Cart buttons?

**Paint**      **5-gallon**    **Color**    **Add to Cart**
**Paint**      **gallon**    **Color**    **Add to Cart**
**Paint**      **Quart**    **Color**    **Add to Cart**

Thanks,
Thomas Pauly

Answer (score 0):

For the best user experience, you may want to build your cart yourself (which would then allow for alternate user interface, such as a drop down for tin size, or a colour picker to choose available shades) - you can then use the XML API to transmit the nice version of the cart to Google.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code for the Google Checkout demo below. It shows how to specify options using drop-downs, radio buttons, checboxes.

https://checkout.google.com/seller/gsc/v2/demo/index.html